# Error when import a mysql table to hdfs using sqoop

Tags: mysql, import, sqoop

I started learning hadoop and am working on some practice myself, here is an issue when I try to use sqoop to import a mysql table to hdfs:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees --username=root -P --table=dept_emp --warehouse-dir=dept_emp -where dept_no='d001' --m 1;
```

The dept_emp has 20k records roughly.

The output is as the following:

> 2016-09-26 16:42:26,467 INFO  [main] ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>
> 2016-09-26 16:42:27,470 INFO  [main] ipc.Client: Retrying connect to
>   server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is
>   RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000
>   MILLISECONDS)

The "Already tried x time(s)" increased from 0 to 9, and then looped again from 0 to 9, hanging there now.

Can someone shed me some light?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct the syntax:

```
--where "dept_no='d001'" 
-m 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for indicating that.